# Initialise array in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a JavaScript programmer trying to learn c++ by porting my JavaScript class to c++. I've found out very quickly that arrays in c++ array very different to those in JavaScript.

Members of my class have array properties. I'm having trouble initialising the array in the constructor. Here's my code.

```
class Name {
  private:
    unsigned int array[];

  public:
    unsigned int getArray();
    Name(unsigned int);
}
//I'm defining everything outside the class because I'm told that's good practice
unsigned int Name::getArray() {
  return this->array;
}
//this is the problem
Name::Name(unsigned int length) {
  this->array = new unsigned int [length];
}
```

I don't have a clue how to fix that last part. I've been messing around with it for ages. Nothing seems to work. The rest of the code is fine, I just get 1 error regarding the constructor.

I'm using g++ to compile.

Comment: If you want an array whose size is decided at run-time, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Have a look at `std::array` too. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: problems: 1. `new` returns a pointer, not an array. 2. You can't assign to an array (you are confusing assignment with initialization).

Comment: Also getArray should return unsigned int*. As suggested above use either std::vector or std::array.

Comment: @skypjack `std::array` needs to have a size known at compile time.

Comment: Yeah, I know, someone suggested to study `std::vector` and I simply extended the suggestion to `std::array`, so to have a deeper view of what the library offers. That's all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code fixed to like like C++ (well more like C):

```
class Name {
  private:
    unsigned int *array;

  public:
    unsigned int *getArray();
    Name(unsigned int);
}
//I'm defining everything outside the class because I'm told that's good practice
unsigned int *Name::getArray() {
  return this->array;
}
//this is the problem
Name::Name(unsigned int length) {
  this->array = new unsigned int [length];
}
```

And now the more C++ way:

```
class Name {
  private:
    std::vector<unsigned int> array;

  public:
    std::vector<unsigned int> getArray(); // Do not worry about optimizations here; check RVO
    Name(unsigned int);
}
//I'm defining everything outside the class because I'm told that's good practice
std::vector<unsigned int> Name::getArray() {
  return array;
}
//this is the problem
Name::Name(unsigned int length) {
  // this line is just to allocate the space for the array, but please keep in ming that you can simply add elements with push_back and the array will grow itself without your explicit memory allocation
  array.resize(length);
}
```

In the first case you define a pointer e.g. an address to a memory location which will hold the array, in the second case you declare an object which will handle the memory for you (well more or less).

Meanwhile take a look at the vector class:

[Vector c++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

One piece of advice for a beginner: try to learn and use the C++ containers (from STL, BOOST), normally the implementations are really good and you don't risk to shoot yourself in the foot (pointers are "dangerous", but as you learn the language you will see that are extremely useful and powerful).

Comment: I would accept but I'm getting "request failed. You can accept an answer in 3 minutes"

Comment: @SneakyTurtle okay; it seems that someone is really pissed off and just down voted me for .... something....

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `std::vector` instead of plain C `array`, especially if you are coming from javascript.

Therefore you can modify your code:

```
class Name {
  public:
     Name(unsigned int);
     unsigned int getArraySize();
     std::vector<unsigned int> getArray();

  private:
    std::vector<unsigned int> _array;
}
```

(In C++ it is a convention to declare first the public member (the most used public API) and then the private members of a class. Usually member variables have naming convention like the one I used `_` or `m_`, to distinguish them.)

```
unsigned int Name::getArraySize() { 
  return _array.size(); 
}

std::vector<unsigned int> getArray() {
   std::vector<unsigned int> outArray;
   outArray = _array;
   return outArray;
}

Name::Name(unsigned int len) 
 : _array(len) 
{  
}
```

The constructor will create an array of `len` dimension, you can look at available constructors at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector.
You can change the length of the array later on, [pushing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) elements into the vector, or [resizing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) it. When accessing the elements with `[i]` take care of keeping the `i < _array.size()`.

The function `getArraySize` returns the number of elements in the array. std:: is the namespace of the Standard Template Library, which is available for all C++ compiler. `size` is the naming for the length of a container (std::vector) in STL.

The function 'getArray' should return a copy of the array, I wrote a prolissic version the short version of the function is `{ return _array; }`.